# psycopg2.errors.AmbiguousColumn: column reference "words" is ambiguous

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, error-handling, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to interface PostgreSQL with Python (v3.9.4).

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
content = 'this is a message'
user = 'Random User'
num_words = len(content.split())
cursor.execute('''
        INSERT INTO Rankings (UserName, Words)
            VALUES (%s, %s)
        ON CONFLICT (UserName)
        DO UPDATE
            SET Words = Words + %s
        ''', (user, num_words, num_words))
```

I have already created a PostgreSQL connection and cursor object correctly. And have created a table as well with 2 columns - UserName and Words.

However, I keep running into the same error:

```
psycopg2.errors.AmbiguousColumn: column reference "words" is ambiguous
LINE 6:             SET Words = Words + 1
^
```

When I change `SET Words = Words + %s` to just `SET Words = %s`, everything works just fine. How do I increment the existing value of Words without causing this error?

Comment: FYI, Postgres 9.5 is EOL as of February 2021. Also are the table column names actually mixed case or lower case?

Comment: They are mixed case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer to this error is to always be specific in naming which table's column you're referring to, even when there's just one table.

I fixed it writing `SET Words = Rankings.Words + %s` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs [ON CONFLICT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT):

> The SET and WHERE clauses in ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE have access to the existing row using the table's name (or an alias), and to rows proposed for insertion using the special excluded table.

So you have to qualify the column with either the table name or the special table `EXCLUDED`.